# launch scripts for gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am moving from Player/Stage/Gazebo to ROS. Working with Gazebo, in Player/Stage/Gazebo used to be with world files (viz. *gazebo pioneer2dx.world*) however in ROS it is with launch files. So, my first question - how to make launch file for the corresponding world file ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11082/launch-scripts-for-gazebo/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-08-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-03**:
@kwc : That is all right !

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-03**:
@Arkapravo: If your issue has been sorted out, I would rather you didn't post -- it will distract from questions that still need answering.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-03**:
@kwc @hsu : Hi Ken, Hi John - the second question has been sorted out. But for the community - I probably should post it as a separate question. Okay with both of you ?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-02**:
Please do not send personal e-mails, and please do not ask separate questions in the same post.  All information must be posted here if you wish for your questions to be answered. I am removing your second question -- please repost with all relevant info if you wish for it to be answered.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-01**:
@hsu : I have sent you an email with the errors

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-01**:
regarding the second question, please clarify "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to [launch Gazebo using an empty world](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo) and then put your_robot (URDF) model into that world you can use:

```
  <!-- Start Gazebo. -->
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>
  <node
    pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" name="gazebo"
    args="$(find gazebo_worlds)/worlds/empty.world">
  </node>
  <node
    pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_your_robot"
    args="-urdf -file $(find your_robot_model)/your_robot.xml -model your_robot">
  </node>
```

Further, you can create a node called your_robot that broadcasts a transform for your robot. If you want to see your robot move in Gazebo, then the your_robot node also needs to publish the state of your robot on the topic gazebo/set_model_state. See [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo) for more details about what ROS Gazebo publishes and subscribes to.

Alternatively, you can use the [Gazebo services](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo) to [make your_robot URDF model move](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API) in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3